# How to change from http localhost to https localhost without create virtual directory

Tags: .net, iis, visual-studio-2019

My project's framework is .net 4.8 and I want to excute using https://localhost protocol so, I was following this article https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/switch-http-to-https-in-visual-studio/ where it shows a simple solution but when I got to this point and I tried to save changes it says that I should create a virtual directory . Is there another way where I do not have to create a virtual directory? why do I have to create it?
[image: we simply change the HTTP protocol here to HTTPS:]

Comment: base on article, I just had to change from http  to https :(

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b very unclear what your comment says: you can have certificate for localhost, and localhost is a domain name (maybe you mean "localhost is not sub-domain of any known top-level domains like '.com' or '.org' "?)....

Comment: All the link does is enable TLS and doesn't mention certificates or authentication.  if you are connecting to local host you are using you user logon credentials and will use a certificate in your stores.  The local directory is where the app homepage would be found.  An HTTP connection need a webpage (html file or equivalent) for the initial homepage.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b I don't see correlation between "no certificate authority is able to provide TLS certificates for the domain 'localhost'" and "thus cannot have a certificate"... Even the link you provided says otherwise...

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. Is your purpose just to access the webpage through https using iis express?